# reading Tweepy data value from tweepy.models.Status object in python is not working

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get information on retweeters for a specific tweet using Tweepy and fetch the in_reply_to_status_id from the returned Tweepy response.

Here is the code

```
 retweets_list = api.get_retweets(id=tweetid)  
 for retweet in retweets_list:
     retweet_json = json.dumps(retweet._json, indent=2)
     retweet_json = json.loads(retweet_json)
     print(retweet_json)
```

The code about above produces the data response below

```
{'created_at': 'Sat Jun 18 06:38:49 +0000 2022', 'id': 1538048568782688256, 'id_str': '1538048568782688256', 'text': 'RT @gyfboxAI: @isle_mcelroy Some mentioned items in thread \n\n@AllisonPDavis  The Governesses  =&gt; httpsurl  The Ob…', 'truncated': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'gyfboxAI', 'name': 'Gyfbox', 'id': 1521109812032978946, 'id_str': '1521109812032978946', 'indices': [3, 12]}, {'screen_name': 'isle_mcelroy', 'name': 'Isle McElroy', 'id': 868462820, 'id_str': '868462820', 'indices': [14, 27]}, {'screen_name': 'AllisonPDavis', 'name': 'Allison P Davis', 'id': 15088579, 'id_str': '15088579', 'indices': [61, 75]}, {'screen_name': 'kvargs93', 'name': 'Katherine Varga', 'id': 885284552897429504, 'id_str': '885284552897429504', 'indices': [125, 134]}], 'urls': [{'url': 'httpsurl', 'expanded_url': 'httpsurlamzn.to/3MUM0mI', 'display_url': 'amzn.to/3MUM0mI', 'indices': [100, 123]}]}, 'source': '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>', 'in_reply_to_status_id': None, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'user': {'id': 1003173584, 'id_str': '1003173584', 'name': 'Elaine Showalter', 'screen_name': 'ecshowalter', 'location': 'Washington, D.C./London', 'description': 'Professor Emerita Princeton U; Anglophile, feminist, theatre fanatic, “The Civil Wars of Julia Ward Howe.” watercolor by Vanessa Bell, “The Queen’s  Tea Party”', 'url': None, 'entities': {'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': 8142, 'friends_count': 1049, 'listed_count': 104, 'created_at': 'Tue Dec 11 03:08:17 +0000 2012', 'favourites_count': 24912, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': True, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': 26489, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_background_image_url': 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_image_url_https': 'httpsurlabs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_tile': True, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/968862619699425281/CKzdSRf6_normal.jpg', 'profile_image_url_https': 'httpsurlpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/968862619699425281/CKzdSRf6_normal.jpg', 'profile_banner_url': 'httpsurlpbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1003173584/1569562029', 'profile_link_color': '0084B4', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'FFFFFF', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'has_extended_profile': False, 'default_profile': False, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none', 'withheld_in_countries': []}, 'geo': None, 'coordinates': None, 'place': None, 'contributors': None, 'retweeted_status': {'created_at': 'Fri Jun 17 17:55:18 +0000 2022', 'id': 1537856423740198913, 'id_str': '1537856423740198913', 'text': '@isle_mcelroy Some mentioned items in thread \n\n@AllisonPDavis  The Governesses  =&gt; httpsurl… httpsurl', 'truncated': True, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'isle_mcelroy', 'name': 'Isle McElroy', 'id': 868462820, 'id_str': '868462820', 'indices': [0, 13]}, {'screen_name': 'AllisonPDavis', 'name': 'Allison P Davis', 'id': 15088579, 'id_str': '15088579', 'indices': [47, 61]}], 'urls': [{'url': 'httpsurl', 'expanded_url': 'httpsurlamzn.to/3MUM0mI', 'display_url': 'amzn.to/3MUM0mI', 'indices': [86, 109]}, {'url': 'httpsurl’, 'expanded_url': 'httpsurltwitter.com/i/web/status/1537856423740198913', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [111, 134]}]}, 'source': '<a href="httpsurlwww.gyfbox.com" rel="nofollow">gyfbox</a>', 'in_reply_to_status_id': 1537835837542604801, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': '1537835837542604801', 'in_reply_to_user_id': 868462820, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': '868462820', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'isle_mcelroy', 'user': {'id': 1521109812032978946, 'id_str': '1521109812032978946', 'name': 'Gyfbox', 'screen_name': 'gyfboxAI', 'location': '', 'description': 'Tag "@GyfboxAI find item" \n\n@GyfboxAI will reply with link for items mentioned in the thread\n\nCOMING SOON !', 'url': 'httpsurlt.co/u7fGrxh24Y', 'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'url': 'httpsurlt.co/u7fGrxh24Y', 'expanded_url': 'httpsurlwww.gyfbox.com', 'display_url': 'gyfbox.com', 'indices': [0, 23]}]}, 'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': 1, 'friends_count': 6, 'listed_count': 0, 'created_at': 'Mon May 02 12:50:32 +0000 2022', 'favourites_count': 1, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': False, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': 49, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': 'F5F8FA', 'profile_background_image_url': None, 'profile_background_image_url_https': None, 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1521109885827661824/iTrlR67U_normal.png', 'profile_image_url_https': 'httpsurlpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1521109885827661824/iTrlR67U_normal.png', 'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'has_extended_profile': True, 'default_profile': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none', 'withheld_in_countries': []}, 'geo': None, 'coordinates': None, 'place': None, 'contributors': None, 'is_quote_status': False, 'retweet_count': 1, 'favorite_count': 0, 'favorited': False, 'retweeted': False, 'possibly_sensitive': False, 'lang': 'en'}, 'is_quote_status': False, 'retweet_count': 1, 'favorite_count': 0, 'favorited': False, 'retweeted': False, 'possibly_sensitive': False, 'lang': 'en'}
```

```
Multiple attempts to extract the in_reply_to_status_id always return "None"

Sample attempt that returned none
```

retweet_json['in_reply_to_status_id']
retweet.in_reply_to_status_id

```
The data return above shows 

'in_reply_to_status_id': 1537835837542604801, 

so I should be getting 1537835837542604801 for in_reply_to_status_id

what am i doing wrong and how can I obtain the in_reply_to_status_id ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Json structure,

the in_reply_status_id is None, the id is in retweeted_status so based on the Json structure

`retweet_json['retweeted_status']['in_reply_to_status_id']`

should give

`1537835837542604801`